# Вытащить данные регулярным выражением

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Надо вытащить данные

```
{
    "list": [
      "test1",
      "test2",
      "test3",
      "test4",
      "test5" 
    ]
 }
```

Вот нужно вытащить test1, test2 и так далее из списка list

Comment: это же json, при чем тут регулярки? C# не умеет в json? Чот сомневаюсь.

Comment: Newtonsoft Json.NET и в путь. Там у него прямо на главной написано как действовать вам: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json Устанавливайте в проект лучше из NuGet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте Json.Net:

```
void Main()
{
    var request = @"{
    ""list"": [
      ""test1"",
      ""test2"",
      ""test3"",
      ""test4"",
      ""test5"" 
    ]
 }";
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(request);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("list")]
    public string[] MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]